# Unable to get user data from php-facebook-login-sdk in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make facebook login using facebook-login-sdk and Codeigniter, I and want to get username and profile picture from facebook but I am unable to solve this problem. I tried more then a week , so this lead me to post my problem on stack overflow.

problem:-
When I click login button I will get redirected to facebook , After accepting app permission I get redirected to **/check** controller with **?code= ...&state=...** at the end of **/check.php** but I am unable to get my data.

**autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','facebook');
```

**my facebook.php inside config folder:-**

```
  $config['facebook_app_id']              = 'my appid';
  $config['facebook_app_secret']          = 'my secret';
  $config['facebook_login_type']          = 'web';
  $config['facebook_login_redirect_url']  = '/check';
  $config['facebook_logout_redirect_url'] = '/home';
  $config['facebook_permissions']         = array('email');
  $config['facebook_graph_version']       = 'v5.6';
  $config['facebook_auth_on_load']        = TRUE;
```

**my /Check controller:-**

```
 class Check extends CI_Controller
 {
    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('facebook');
      $this->load->model('User');
    }

   public function index(){
      $userData = array();
      if($this->facebook->is_authenticated()){
         $fbUserProfile = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me? 
         fields=id,first_name');
         $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
         $userData['oauth_uid'] = $fbUserProfile['id'];
         $userData['first_name'] = $fbUserProfile['first_name'];
         print_r($userData['first_name']);
         $data['logoutURL'] = $this->facebook->logout_url();
      }else{
         $data['authURL'] =  $this->facebook->login_url();
         echo('sorry');
      }
    }
 }
```

**This is Facebook.php libraries folder**

```
 require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php'; 

 use Facebook\Facebook as FB;
 use Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken;
 use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
 use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;
 use Facebook\Helpers\FacebookJavaScriptHelper;
 use Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
 Class Facebook
 {
  private $fb;
  private $helper;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->load->config('facebook');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    if (!isset($this->fb)){
        $this->fb = new FB([
            'app_id'                => $this->config->item('facebook_app_id'),
            'app_secret'            => $this->config->item('facebook_app_secret'),
            'default_graph_version' => $this->config->item('facebook_graph_version')
        ]);
    }
    switch ($this->config->item('facebook_login_type')){
        case 'js':
            $this->helper = $this->fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
            break;
        case 'canvas':
            $this->helper = $this->fb->getCanvasHelper();
            break;
        case 'page_tab':
            $this->helper = $this->fb->getPageTabHelper();
            break;
        case 'web':
            $this->helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            break;
    }
    if ($this->config->item('facebook_auth_on_load') === TRUE){
        $this->authenticate();
    }
}

public function object(){
    return $this->fb;
}

public function is_authenticated(){
    $access_token = $this->authenticate();
    if(isset($access_token)){
        return $access_token;
    }
    return false;
}

public function request($method, $endpoint, $params = [], $access_token = null){
    try{
        $response = $this->fb->{strtolower($method)}($endpoint, $params, $access_token);
        return $response->getDecodedBody();
    }catch(FacebookResponseException $e){
        return $this->logError($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
    }catch (FacebookSDKException $e){
        return $this->logError($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function login_url(){
    if($this->config->item('facebook_login_type') != 'web'){
        return '';
    }
    return $this->helper->getLoginUrl(
        base_url() . $this->config->item('facebook_login_redirect_url'),
        $this->config->item('facebook_permissions')
    );
}

public function logout_url(){
    if($this->config->item('facebook_login_type') != 'web'){
        return '';
    }
    return $this->helper->getLogoutUrl(
        $this->get_access_token(),
        base_url() . $this->config->item('facebook_logout_redirect_url')
    );
}

public function destroy_session(){
    $this->session->unset_userdata('fb_access_token');
}

private function authenticate(){
    $access_token = $this->get_access_token();
    if($access_token && $this->get_expire_time() > (time() + 30) || $access_token && !$this->get_expire_time()){
        $this->fb->setDefaultAccessToken($access_token);
        return $access_token;
    }
    if(!$access_token){
        try{
            $access_token = $this->helper->getAccessToken();
        }catch (FacebookSDKException $e){
            $this->logError($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        if(isset($access_token)){
            $access_token = $this->long_lived_token($access_token);
            $this->set_expire_time($access_token->getExpiresAt());
            $this->set_access_token($access_token);
            $this->fb->setDefaultAccessToken($access_token);
            return $access_token;
        }
    }
    if($this->config->item('facebook_login_type') === 'web'){
        if($this->helper->getError()){
            $error = array(
                'error'             => $this->helper->getError(),
                'error_code'        => $this->helper->getErrorCode(),
                'error_reason'      => $this->helper->getErrorReason(),
                'error_description' => $this->helper->getErrorDescription()
            );
            return $error;
        }
    }
    return $access_token;
}

private function long_lived_token(AccessToken $access_token){
    if(!$access_token->isLongLived()){
        $oauth2_client = $this->fb->getOAuth2Client();
        try{
            return $oauth2_client->getLongLivedAccessToken($access_token);
        }catch (FacebookSDKException $e){
            $this->logError($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
    return $access_token;
}

private function get_access_token(){
    return $this->session->userdata('fb_access_token');
}

private function set_access_token(AccessToken $access_token){
    $this->session->set_userdata('fb_access_token', $access_token->getValue());
}

private function get_expire_time(){
    return $this->session->userdata('fb_expire');
}

private function set_expire_time(DateTime $time = null){
    if ($time) {
        $this->session->set_userdata('fb_expire', $time->getTimestamp());
    }
}

private function logError($code, $message){
    log_message('error', '[FACEBOOK PHP SDK] code: ' . $code.' | message: '.$message);
    return ['error' => $code, 'message' => $message];
}

public function __get($var){
    return get_instance()->$var;
}
```

}

This is latest version sdk .
I followed [enter link description here](https://www.codexworld.com/facebook-login-codeigniter/)

My Folder Structure:-

[image]

Please Help Me ??

Comment: So what happens, do you get to see the “Sorry”, because is_authenticated actually returned false?`If not, what does a var_dump of $fbUserProfile look like?

Comment: @misorude when I **var_dump($this->facebook->is_authenticated())** it returns Bool(false) and where i **var_dump($fbUserProfile)** outside if block it returns **array(2) { ["error"]=> int(0) ["message"]=> string(33) "You must provide an access token." }**

Comment: @misorude please help me , I think I can't solve this problem.